# Слово "завсегдатай" во множественном числе

Tags: морфология

Хочу написать предложение со словом "завсегдатай" во множественном числе. Никак не соображу, как правильно написать.
"И тогда эти посетители станут завсегдата...." ????

Answer (score 2):

Завсегдатаями (полицаями, самураями и т. д.).

Comment: Ой, спасибо огромное! А то я тут думала, думала и написала завсегдатыми.

Comment: А по-моему, завсегдатые звучит понятнее, чем завсегдатаи!

Answer (score 1):

Однозначно: завсегдатаями.

Answer (score 0):

В случае возникновения подобных вопросов, можно обратиться к словарям, содержащим формы слов, например [к этому](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_forms/18414/завсегдатай) или [к этому](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/завсегдатай).